# JSoup Parse without Correcting HTML

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

I simply want to escape the contents of all PRE tags within my HTML. To do this I am currently using JSoup which is working as expected except for one thing. The example input String I am using:

```
<pre>public List<Article> methodName() {
    ...
}</pre>
```

So from this String, I would simply want to ecape the `<` and `>` characters. I am currently doing this using JSoup as follows (I am using Spring HtmlUtils for escaping):

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(string);
document.outputSettings().prettyPrint(false);
Elements codeTags = document.select("pre");
for (Element codeTag : codeTags) {
    codeTag.html(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape(codeTag.html()));
}
```

Which seems to work as expected except for the above input String, where it seems to auto-change and "fix" the `<Article>` text, as shown below:

```
<pre>public List<article> methodName() {
    ...
}</article></pre>
```

I understand that JSoup is parsing HTML, but this is not behaviour I want in this situation, is there anything I can do to tell JSoup not to try to autofix my HTML? Should I be using JSoup in the first place?

Comment: Why do you think that your sample string is related in any way to XML? The fact that it contains brackets do not convert it into XML or HTML of any kind...

Comment: @SJuan76 In my case, that sample string is the contents of a HTML PRE tag, I am using JSoup to get those PRE tags and their contents.

Comment: Do you mean like in the edit I just made? (I hope it will make the question clearer)

Comment: @SJuan76 Yes exactly like that, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Understood, and that's my issue. The <Article> is within my PRE tag, which I'm getting with JSoup. I am then escaping those characters within the PRE tags. However when JSoup originally parsed the HTML, it modified that text (lower casing it, and closing the tag), I just need JSoup to return me the PRE tag Elements, unmodified, for me to escape.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Correct me if I'm wrong, but a SAX Parser will be unable to parse HTML tags, as it is not well-formed XML.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Ok, could you answer this question with a working example, as I'm not sure what you're referring to.

Comment: But, from where you get these "HTML"? they are not HTML complaint, at least the tag should have the chars escaped. If you open it in a browser it probably wont display correctly.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento The HTML comes from the DB from plain text, I don't want authors when they write code to manually type in the escaped characters, I want Java to do this programmatically.

Comment: So you should do the escape before inserting on the DB but without user ask. Does the authors write the article in HTML?

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento The article is written in a textarea. I'd rather not store the escaped characters in the DB, i'd rather have that generated in the view.

Comment: Well, any working HTML editor will escape the chars, if the authors are free to use HTML and other tags without escape the result will be a bunch of fix will you need to do at render time. There's a high security risk too, as the authors could put a script redirecting to other page (just an example). You should limit the tags of HTML the authors could use, and escape the others. Anyway, if you don't want to do this its your choice. Best wishes.

Comment: Did you find any clue? I'm facing the same issue : I'm parsing nodes containing Java Code (e.g. code in which there is stuff that JSoup understands as HTML opening tags), and JSoup keep *autofixing* it...